# Prepare data for creating voxel layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I try to create a voxel layer using ArcGIS Pro. In my raster, I choose an area to show height changes using a voxel layer. I create random points in this area and have assigned Z values to these points. After that, I used the Empirical Bayesian Kriging 3D tool and finally, I used GA layer 3D to NetCDF tool. After these steps, the voxel layer was created, but after opening it in the local scene, when I share it as a web layer and when I want to display this published layer on my web map that I created using ArcGIS JS API, I constantly get a layer could not be created error. Is there a mistake in creating a Voxel Layer? Which other method can I create it?